# Can I render data inview of an element using amp-list?

Tags: amp-html

I want render another article inview of the an element in the dom of the amp page. Can I do using amp-list?
Does amp-list triggers ajax request inview of the element or onload of the page?

Comment: Check the [amp-list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list) docs and tell us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

If the supplied template (see more [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-templates.md)) is set up to format the data supplied by your JSON endpoint you specify in your `amp-list` you could display it.

I think it loads things as dynamically as possible, the best thing to do would be to try it and run it through the validator and see what happens!